# gradle init - not doing what the getting started tutorial says it should

Tags: gradle, documentation

According to this page:
https://docs.gradle.org/current/samples/sample_building_kotlin_applications.html#run_the_init_task
running `gradle init` will give me a list of options.

Nope, it doesn't; it just says "build successful" and constructs the directory structure without the app directory.

I imagine I am meant to have set up some default somethings somewhere. Not having used gradle before I do not know what to call the somethings so I can search for them, nor the names of where they should go. Anyone know where the instructions for putting something somewhere are? If you can answer this, you probably know people who might improve the documentation - which would save you answering stupid questions like this one :-)

P

In response to the request below, this is the full output using -i:

```
pi@dadsDesktop:~/tmpry/demo $ gradle -i init
Initialized native services in: /home/pi/.gradle/native
The client will now receive all logging from the daemon (pid: 27866). The daemon log file: /home/pi/.gradle/daemon/4.4.1/daemon-27866.out.log
Starting 2nd build in daemon [uptime: 1 mins 43.436 secs, performance: 98%]
Using 4 worker leases.
Creating new cache for fileHashes, path /home/pi/tmpry/demo/.gradle/4.4.1/fileHashes/fileHashes.bin, access org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess@358daf
Starting Build
Settings evaluated using settings file '/home/pi/tmpry/demo/settings.gradle'.
Projects loaded. Root project using build file '/home/pi/tmpry/demo/build.gradle'.
Included projects: [root project 'demo']

> Configure project : 
Evaluating root project 'demo' using build file '/home/pi/tmpry/demo/build.gradle'.

All projects evaluated.
Selected primary task 'init' from project :
Tasks to be executed: [task ':wrapper', task ':init']
Creating new cache for resourceHashesCache, path /home/pi/tmpry/demo/.gradle/4.4.1/fileHashes/resourceHashesCache.bin, access org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess@358daf
Creating new cache for taskHistory, path /home/pi/tmpry/demo/.gradle/4.4.1/taskHistory/taskHistory.bin, access org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess@b60cd6
Creating new cache for outputFiles, path /home/pi/tmpry/demo/.gradle/buildOutputCleanup/outputFiles.bin, access org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess@179e5c6
:wrapper (Thread[Daemon worker Thread 2,5,main]) started.

> Task :wrapper 
Putting task artifact state for task ':wrapper' into context took 0.0 secs.
Up-to-date check for task ':wrapper' took 0.009 secs. It is not up-to-date because:
  No history is available.

:wrapper (Thread[Daemon worker Thread 2,5,main]) completed. Took 0.32 secs.
:init (Thread[Daemon worker Thread 2,5,main]) started.

> Task :init 
Putting task artifact state for task ':init' into context took 0.0 secs.
Up-to-date check for task ':init' took 0.0 secs. It is not up-to-date because:
  Task has not declared any outputs.

:init (Thread[Daemon worker Thread 2,5,main]) completed. Took 0.114 secs.

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 2s
2 actionable tasks: 2 executed
```

Comment: Hi Petr. How can actually help you? What is your question? If your only point is that documentation is false, then you can open an issue with Gradle on their Github repository.

Comment: Doesn't it say more than "build succeded"? Normally there are informational messages before that. If not, try running with `-i` and post the full output here.

Comment: Thanks guys. I have done a grand search and nobody else seems to have had this problem.  I guess it is me, not really the documentation.  When I get an answer I will put something appropriate on the issues list on Github.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that with old versions of gradle (such as the version on a raspberry pi you get with `apt-get install gradle` circa Nov 2020) you need to specify the type of thing you want to produce using the  `--type` option, and the structure(?) of the project.  In my case with `--dsl kotlin`

These attributes are specified in the documentation under "plug-ins".  Just for those who think that is obvious, the other way to specify these elements is to run it in a context (whatever that is) where gradle can figure it out for itself. This is apparently the normal way it is used.  Unfortunately the context available to me ( kotlin/gradle/inteliJ ) does not work on a pi. Using `make` is not easier, but I suspect not harder, and I'd bet `make` is more stable :-/

Answer (score 0):

As @Petr wrote, the problem is that you have an old version of gradle, probably provided by your OS/package manager.

I think the best is to install a more recent one. On ubuntu, I used snap to install a more recent one:

```
sudo snap install gradle --classic
```